# How to create an Accordion ListView in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, accordion

I know how to create a ListView in Android but I need some kind of accordion list view in Android. Something like this:

[image]

The accordion list should have a section header and should toggle when clicking on the section header.

**How can I build such an accordion ListView?**

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ExpandableListView`. Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Answer (score 0):

you change child_view.xml content.

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/

Answer (score 0):

I have build a super light Accordion list recently via Constraint layout . It's worth to have a look at :

https://github.com/draxdave/ConstraintAccordion

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Why would you use ListView? Android has something new now called RecyclerView which takes place for the ListView: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html
Here is the way of making a header using RecyclerView:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class HeaderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
String[] data;

public HeaderAdapter(String[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
        return new VHItem(null);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
        return new VHHeader(null);
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof VHItem) {
        String dataItem = getItem(position);
        //cast holder to VHItem and set data
    } else if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
        //cast holder to VHHeader and set data for header.
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.length + 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return TYPE_HEADER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}

private String getItem(int position) {
    return data[position - 1];
}

class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;

    public VHItem(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Button button;

    public VHHeader(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

}

Link on git: https://gist.github.com/hister/d56c00fb5fd2dfaf279b

Comment: How would we implement an expand/collapse logic for each header ?

Comment: Because recyclerView is complicated as fk, compared to listview